# Stop derived class from being initialized

Tags: c#, class, radix

I have a base class, which I'd like to use to do some checks before of initializing a derived class..

```
class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass(Object Param)
    {
        // Do checks
    }
}
```

I also (of course) have the derived class

```
class NewClass : BaseClass
{
    public NewClass(Object Param) : base(Param)
    {
        // Code here
    }
}
```

Now, I'd like to have a situation like the following

If the check in the base class fails, then I'd like the code in the derived class (// Code here) do not get executed at all.

Is this possible? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 9):

Do not write a "[vexing exception](http://ericlippert.com/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/)". **The derived class has to have a way to know whether or not the base class ctor is going to throw.** Otherwise you are not making it easy for the author of the derived class to prevent the bug.

The right thing to do is to (1) make it very easy for the caller of the derived class to know whether the exception is going to be thrown or not, and (2) **crash them without mercy if they get it wrong**. Make it hurt to pass you bad data, and easy to avoid that pain, and you will end up never throwing that exception because your derived classes will avoid the pain.

Answer (score 3):

The best you could do is have the base class constructor throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible, yes, just throw an exception.  Then you can be sure the derived class's code won't be called.  Is it a good idea?  Maybe, but possibly not.  It's considered bad form to throw an exception in a constructor.

A less mean option would be to have a protected field/property `isValid` that you set in the base class constructor.  The derived class can then only do stuff `if(isValid)`.  As long as you know you'll play nice with yourself this will work.

Comment: Is it considered bad form to throw in a constructor?  I have heard that having a zombie object (one whos initialization failed) is considered bad form.  Makes more sense to me to throw in the constructor, that way you can't avoid but to deal with it, if you have to check `isValid` everywhere, it becomes cumbersome and error prone.  What are you supposed to do if `isValid` is false, nothing?

Comment: Well, it depends a bit on the specifics.  Note I don't say that you shouldn't ever throw in a constructor, it's more that it's indicative of some underlying design problem and you should consider possible ways of re-designing the class.  For example, maybe you're trying to do too much in the constructor.  Maybe there should be some sort of Init method that's called, or you're simply doing some sort of work that belongs in a method outside of the constructor.  If not, then go ahead and throw the exception.

Comment: As for the isValid, that's more of a technical solution to the problem asked, and I couldn't really speak to it's appropriateness/use without more details.

Comment: The problem is that the base class should be implemented from multiple (a lot!) other classes, so I think it's a bit ugly to have the 'IsValid' in each of them.... It would be better at this point to use the exception, I suppose...

Answer (score 1):

You can have the base constructor throw an exception if your check fails.

You can implement the so-called null object pattern, where you have an internal `isValid` member. You can set it to `false` based on your check in the base constructor and have all your methods do nothing if `isValid` is false.

The best way, which also removes the need for the exception, is to use the factory pattern. Simply delegate the object creation to a factory object/method which performs the check and either creates the derived object or not, based on your check.

Comment: Could you please explain this factory pattern? Thank you

Comment: @user1264377: A simple way: Avoid public constructors and have a public method which calls the constructor.  This method will perform the validation and will return `null` if that validation fails.  Personally, I'd rather have the validation methods be public and throw an exception (which should *not be caught* - the caller will call those methods to guarantee no exceptions will occur), which is probably in line with [Eric Lippert's Advice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9794607/18192).  However, Andrei's solution ties the validation more closely to object creation, which may be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, just throw an exception.  Creation of the object will immediately fail, and the derived constructor will not run.

Answer (score 0):

After you check your code in base class, set a property value in the base class. You can access that in the child class and decide whether to continue or not

```
class BaseClass
{
    public bool IsValid {set;get;}
    public BaseClass(Object Param)
    {
        // Do checks and set the value of property
         this.IsValid=false; // or true
    }
}

class NewClass : BaseClass
{
    public NewClass(Object Param) : base(Param)
    {
        if(this.IsValid)
        {
          // Code here
        }
    }
}
```